# Best Practices for Wiki Images (and other assets)

Tags: 2013, document-library, enterprise-wiki, image-upload

I am new to SharePoint and am setting up an Enterprise Wiki Site for knowledge management. I am struggling to determine the best way to support images and other assets related to a wiki page. I have been experimenting with Image, Document, and Asset libraries within the site to house the files. My primary concern is the potential for name collisions if everyone is dropping their screenshots, etc. into the root of the library.

When uploading via the editor, the Image library seems to be handling this nicely by creating a folder structure to isolate the images by page. This would be perfect if the other library types would do something similar, but they seem to just be dropping the files in the root. Is there something I can do to turn this "feature" on for the other libraries? Or is there a different setup altogether that I should be considering? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the obvious setting which controls the behavior I wanted. 
Library Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Site Assets Library = Yes